# Data is getting right aligned

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, textwidth

Hello I am using following code to generate table.
My requirement is to generate table which fits to text width.

```latex
\begin{table}[b]\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.0}\setlength\LTleft{0pt}\setlength\LTright{0pt}
\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} |l|l|l|l| }
\hline
&Written by&Checked by&Approved by\\\hline

\endfirsthead
\hline
&Written by&Checked by&Approved by\\\hline

\endhead
Department&Sales&&\\\hline
Name&ABCD&&\\\hline
Signature&&&\\\hline
Date&21-01-2009&17-06-2019&17-06-2019\\\hline

\end{longtable}\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.0}\end{table}
```

but content is getting right aligned, even if I have mentioned it as center.

[image]

Comment: First of why do you have a longtable inside a table float? That does not make sense. Either remove the `table` env, or convert the `longtable` into tabular. Remember that longtables can break across pages, while th3e table env cannot.

Comment: Next, what is the purpose of `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}`? Lastly, it is custom here to add a full (but minimal) example along with ones question. This is just a sniplet, and thus those wanting to help have to fill in the rest in order to test your code (in contrast to a minimal example, where one can just copy the code and test as is). Questions with sniplets rather than MWEs tends to get less attention.

Comment: @daleif  I have longtable inside a table float, to position it bottom of the page.

Comment: Again longtables should not be used inside a floating table, it defies the purpose of longtable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `xltabular` environment, which brings the functionalities of `longtable` to `tabularx`.

Also, I replaced changing the value of `\arraystretch`, which increases the rows height asymmetrically, with the `\makegapedcells` command, from `makecell`, so the cells contents be vertically centred.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{makecell}
\setcellgapes{6pt}

\begin{document}

{\makegapedcells
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{ |*{4}{X|}}
\hline
&Written by&Checked by&Approved by \\
\hline
\endfirsthead
\hline
&Written by&Checked by&Approved by \\
\hline
\endhead
Department&Sales&& \\
\hline
Name&ABCD&& \\
\hline
Signature&&&\\\hline
Date&21-01-2009&17-06-2019&17-06-2019 \\
\hline
\end{xltabular}}

\end{document}
```

[image]